# VBA Outlook 2010. Extracting specific outlook body text to excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

There are a few posts open on this topic however none  seem to fully do what I need. I have done a little bit of programming however I have never done anything with VBA. Every day I receive a series of emails varying from 10 to 50 all containing a subject line starting with [Tk#*******] New Request ( * = 7 digit number) 
Then inside the body text there is a form that looks like this:

[Body Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3wCo.png)

I then have an excel sheet set up with 'Username' in 'C', 'Company' in 'G', 'valid until' in 'H' and 'Ticket' in 'I'. I would like to extract first the 7 digit ticket number from the subject and put it in the excel 'Ticket' field, then just the 'smithjoh' part from the login field and place it in 'Username', then the External company listed to 'Company' and finally the Expiration date into 'valid until'.

First I would like to know if this is possible to do as it is extracting specific sections of the data and if so if someone could help me out with making this work that'd be most appreciated. I have attempted to do it myself however lack of experience has left me clueless therefor there is nothing to work with unfortunately. If this could be made it would help me out a lot as it would automate a very tedious manual task.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Starting with TK? Getting email from storm troopers? Do you have something that you have tried and it failed that you can post here? That is usually received best as there are many ways to skin a cat. If you have tried and failed, it might be a couple quick edits to make it work.

Comment: All I have tried so far is copying the entire body of a text which works great. I have looked around online to attempt to find a way to only grap specific text however there doesn't really seem to be anything on it. I really have no idea where to even start, sorry. Tk stands for ticket, it's an automated ticket number :P

Comment: For specific text, you can use Regular Expressions, or combinations of Instr and Mid, or even Split.  It also depends on whether the body or your email is merely text, or is a table.  You should provide code and indicate the problems you have run into.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you are grabbing the body and title without issue then you just need to do string manipulations. Read them into a variable each. Assuming that your subject is litterally "TK#******* New Request" then this should get you started. Basically repeat this logic for each part you want to pull out. Once you have the values in variables you can then put those values into cells.

```
Dim sSubject as string
Dim sBody as string
Dim sTicket as string
Dim sLogin as string
Dim lLoginPos as long
Dim iLoginLength as integer

sTicket = Mid(sSubject,4,7) 'start 4th char and grab 7 ... if you actually have the brackets in the subject then do 5,7

lLoginPos = InStr(sBody, "emea") + 5 'if they aren't all emea you will need to key off the "Req on behalf name" and add more to the result the result will be the e in emea so add 5 to get past that to the login.
iLoginLength = InStr(sBody, "Req on behalf mail") - lLoginPos ' you might need to subtract an additional 1 or 2 if your result isn't perfect. Not sure what the blank white spaces in your screenshot will do here.
sLogin = Mid(sBody,lLoginPos,iLoginLength) ' grabs that username. 
With Sheets("Sheet1")
  cells(1,3) = sLogin ' puts that into Row 1 Colum 3 (C) Cells is R1C1 ... backwards from the normal way you think of excel
End With
```

Use other string variables for all the other parts you want to grab and just repeat the logic of finding the starting place and ending place and then using mid to put it into a variable.

Give it a shot filling out the rest and if you get stuck, post your code up to that point and let us know what line is giving you trouble. **Don't forget to turn on your locals window and use your F8 key to step through the code one line at a time so that you can see exactly what is going on.** This is especially useful with string manipulations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a go and let you know if I have any problems.

Comment: Well l appreciate the code and I follow what is going on however I have to admit that I have had exactly zero experience with VBA and macro programming previous to this therefor I am still completely stuck. I realize it is probably not the purpose of this forum to ask for code to do something and someone does it for you but that is essentially what I require. Thanks anyway for your help but I should probably go and learn the basics first before tackling such a task.

Comment: You had mentioned you had gone through some other posts and they didn't do what you need. Do they do part of it and you are just having trouble modifying it or what have you tried? That wasn't actually a compete Sub to accomplish what you need. Based on your posts I thought you were successfully pulling the text from the emails into excel already and just needed help with getting the strings out of it. What have you tried? Where you at with the project?

Comment: So I can pull all complete fields using other posts code and essentially copy and pasting, so this includes the sender, the receiver, time sent, entire body. However like I said before I have no knowledge of VBA syntax or what is actually required to get it running. I did take some other code and try to replace the internals with your code (replacing the previous extraction with the specific ones) however that gave me errors, I'm guessing due to missing code. Essentially I don't really know enough about what is happening to be able to modify.